# how to backup html 5 local storage data

Tags: javascript, jquery

am developing an offline application using html 5 and java script libraries.
my system is for offline data collection. data is stored in the local machine in text format before being synced to the server later on.
before i had developed the same application but using silver light which was easy to back up data for security reasons using

any idea on how i can backup the text files and zip them to my hard disk will be highly appreciated.

i have not found a solid answer through my research so far
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the Javascript filesystem API? Or you could dump the data into a textbox and prompt the user to copy and paste it to a file somewhere (I'd base64-encode the content first and add checksums though).

Comment: @Dai,sounds a cool idea to dump the data into a text box and prompt the user to copy and paste it to a file somewhere..if u could provide a snippet code of how that will work the better because the data is stored in key(name of the .txt file) and value(the contents in the .txt file).then the files backed up using the text box should be able to be loaded to a different application without need to change anything in it for syncing.am developing my application using html5 and jquery mobile.thanks in andvance

Answer (score 3):

One "solution" I can think of is, before the user closes the app using the close button, you could detect the `window.onbeforeunload` event and send the data to your server to save. But this is not reliable because there might be cases when the browser may crash or the user might forcefully close the browser application. Or worst of all if you are constantly using localStorage and by chance the user clears the browsing data (which includes localStorage) it will be gone.

But assuming you have the data at hand, you can send it to the server using `POST` and make a script to save it in the disk. Obviously, you might want to impose limitation on file size and enforce other security restrictions.

### WARNING: PHP

Lets say you have a folder created for each unique user and all files in each user's folder are guaranteed to be named uniquely. In PHP you can use functions like `file_put_contents()` to save a text file, you can also easily ZIP it using the `ZipArchive` class.

It's not recommended to store this kind of data directly to the drive. I would highly recommend you to put the localStorage data in some kind of database and do a database backup instead of backing up individual user's data.

As other users have pointed it out you could also look at the HTML5 File API. Examples [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Comment: NullGeo thanks for your reply....my application is to be used 100% in offline situations(ares where there is no internet connectivity at all) then the data entry clerks back up the data and send to the head office where syncing will be done after verifying that the data is valid.so instant sending to the server cant work.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution on how to backup local storage files and zip them to my local drive without any server code. Below is a code snippet that works fine for me at least for now. Any modifications and enhancements will be highly appreciated.

```
if (localStorageKeys.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorageKeys.length; i++) {
        var key = localStorageKeys[i];
        if (key.search(_instrumentId) != -1) {
            keysToBackup.push(key);
            var data = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKeys[i]);
            zip.file(localStorageKeys[i].slice(0, -19) + ".txt", data);
        }
        else {
            keysNotToBackup.push(key);
        }
        var datafile = document.getElementById('backupData');
        datafile.download = formName + "_Data.zip";
        datafile.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(zip.generate({ type: "blob" }));

    }
}
```

Comment: there is a lot of code missing, you might wanna add the missing parts?

Comment: This appears to be the location of the "missing parts"
https://github.com/Stuk/jszip

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for backup and restoring the local storage of websites.

You can use this repository:

https://github.com/todvora/localstorage-backup

This is the live app:

https://www.tomas-dvorak.cz/localstorage-backup/

Usage:

1. In the live app, Drag the buttons and drop them into your bookmarks. They are so-called bookmarklets.
2. Open the site you want to backup/restore and click on this bookmarked button.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31792963)